# Android Studio in VSCode

Tags: java, android

I am completely new to Android Studio and have found it quite bulky and tried to do it on VSCode. I don't know how to proceed with this.
I am also having a problem regarding the [SDK path (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZaqS.png)

So far I am confused as to how to proceed

[Screenshot of VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4naSd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please only use Android Studio for Android development. It's Google recommended. You're actually making it harder on yourself, by "Reeinventing the wheel".

Just learn how the IDE works (Android studio). Take it step by step. It takes time to learn new things. Be patient